# token or hash value to store and charge a unique customer: Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have read the documentation and currently it supports the `customer profile` which i can use to charge the customer. I want to know if it is possible i can have a token which i stored in my `user` table along with each user and then charge that? like a hash value or the token without using the `profile ids`? or the only `profile id` is the way to charge the customer.

Actually i want to do the recurring payment manually because of returning customer and having inconsistent monthly utility bill.

Another reason is that `profile` it made consist on `name` `description` and `email` which i think is not good enough to check the uniqueness of the users profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use the [Customer Information Manager (CIM) API](https://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim/) to create a payment profile. You then will have a payment profile ID for that payment profile that you can charge against without having to know or store any of that credit card information.

The profile ID is the only way to charge the customer. There is no token or hash.

Comment: sorry i have edited my question actually i was hoping other solution and not using the `profile ids`. i have already read the documentation of authorise.net [this](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-customer-profile)

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Basically, the profile ID is also you get and is what you have to use.

Comment: Okay so i was reading the right documentation. On the first customer which profile does not exist i have to create the new profile and stored it in my local database. upon returning i have to charge that again ? this is the right way to do it ?

Comment: Perfect sir ! Thank you for clarifying.